# Webページのライセンス違反を判断してほしい

Tags: ライセンス

プログラマが
知るべき97のこと
http://xn--97-273ae6a4irb6e2hsoiozc2g4b8082p.com/

はてブでホッテントリ入りしていて気になってるのですが、
このサイトってオライリーに無断で作られたサイトっぽいんです。

これって完全にアウトですよね?

Comment: 「このサイトはライセンス違反なのか」という方向の質問は、オフトピック扱いになります。(参考: [メタでの投稿](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1541/30)。) オライリーが指定しているライセンスを示し、そのライセンスの適用に関する疑問を挙げるという形であればよいと思います。

Answer (score 8):

[Creative Commons — 表示 3.0 アメリカ合衆国 — CC BY 3.0 US](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/deed.ja)を読んで、ご自身で判断されてください。厳密な法解釈はこのサイトではオフトピックとなります。

あくまで個人の見解としては、トップページの画像で各著者の肖像権を侵害している可能性はあるのかなと思いました。しかし、O'ReillyのCommonsにご丁寧にも各著者の画像も公開されているので、適法のようにも見えます。

尚、英語版はかなり以前から[公開](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/97_Things_Every_Programmer_Should_Know)されています。